# Why aren't google charts loading until I refresh

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have been using google charts for a while without any problems. My code hasn't changed at all, but just lately my charts have not been loading, until I refresh the browser a few times, and wait, and then refresh again. When the charts do load they are fine. I can go to other pages and come back, and they load instantly. I will say now I load my jquery after my html rather than before, that doubley makes sure the page is loaded before the jquery.

I am using mozilla firefox. If I don't close down the browser everything is fine, but as soon as I close the browser and go back to the page the charts will not show straight away. Which makes me think that once it is in the cache everything is fine, but I think there is a problem getting the loader.js from google charts.

I include the google chart using the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Then I include my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/charts.js"></script>
```

Originally I didn't put my code in document ready, but I added that recently to make sure the page had loaded before running my code.

Then here is my charts.js jQuery code to load the chart (I obviously include jquery, but not shown that here)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post("database/home/ajax/ajax.php",  {CODE:"loadCharts"}, function(data){

        google.charts.load('current', {
          callback: function () {

            myData1=data.chart.splice(0,data.salesCount);
            myData2=data.chart.splice(0,data.expensesCount);
            myData3=data.chart.splice(0,data.hrcostCount);

            drawBarChart('total_sales_chart',myData1,"Total Sales Last Six Months","Sales");
            drawBarChart('total_expenses_chart',myData2,"Total Expenses Last Six Months","Expenses");
            drawBarChart('total_hr_chart',myData3,"Total HR Costs Last Six Months","HR Costs");

            function drawBarChart(id,myData,title,axis) {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
                data.addColumn('number', axis);

                var dataLength= myData.length;

                var rows = new Array();     

                for(var i = 0; i < dataLength ; i++) {
                    rows.push([new Date(myData[i][0]),0]);
                }
                data.addRows(rows);

                var options = {
                    title: title,
                    hAxis: {
                        title: axis
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        title: 'Month'
                    },
                    backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
                    legend: {position: 'none'},
                    'animation':{duration:1000,easing:'out'}
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById(id));
                chart.draw(data, options);

                setTimeout(function(){  
                    for(i=0;i<dataLength;i++){
                        data.setValue(i,1,myData[i][1]);
                    }
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                },1000);    
            }
          },
          packages: ['corechart']
        });
    },"JSON");
});
```

The post is where I get my data from the backend. I know my post is ok because it comes back instantly, but I do know that the code after the callback is not running, every time. Which means for some reason I don't think loader.js is downloading properly.

Once the charts do show everything is fine. Can anyone tell me why the charts don't load when the page first loads?

If you are wondering about the splice I can tell you about that. I bring back all my data in one array and then split them up into 3 arrays, so I only have to make the one post for 3 charts. There is nothing wrong with my arrays however, just the google chart callback.

Comment: Any errors in the developer console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this. Even though I disabled my addon popup blocker to see if this was causing the problem there was something I didn't know. Mozilla Firefox has a built in popup blocker. Under tools/options/Content. You need to untick block popup windows, and then google charts will load fine into mozilla. This has been bugging me for weeks, and I didn't even know it had a built in popup blocker.

Answer (score 0):

google's `callback` can be used in place of --> `$(document).ready`

try calling `google.load` before anything else

if the `callback` fires, and the `$.post` works,
then there should be no delay in drawing the charts

try restructuring as seen in the following snippet...

---

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  callback: function () {
    $.post("database/home/ajax/ajax.php",  {CODE:"loadCharts"}, function(data){
        myData1=data.chart.splice(0,data.salesCount);
        myData2=data.chart.splice(0,data.expensesCount);
        myData3=data.chart.splice(0,data.hrcostCount);

        drawBarChart('total_sales_chart',myData1,"Total Sales Last Six Months","Sales");
        drawBarChart('total_expenses_chart',myData2,"Total Expenses Last Six Months","Expenses");
        drawBarChart('total_hr_chart',myData3,"Total HR Costs Last Six Months","HR Costs");

        function drawBarChart(id,myData,title,axis) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
            data.addColumn('number', axis);

            var dataLength= myData.length;

            var rows = new Array();

            for(var i = 0; i < dataLength ; i++) {
                rows.push([new Date(myData[i][0]),0]);
            }
            data.addRows(rows);

            var options = {
                title: title,
                hAxis: {
                    title: axis
                },
                vAxis: {
                    title: 'Month'
                },
                backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
                legend: {position: 'none'},
                'animation':{duration:1000,easing:'out'}
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById(id));
            chart.draw(data, options);

            setTimeout(function(){
                for(i=0;i<dataLength;i++){
                    data.setValue(i,1,myData[i][1]);
                }
                chart.draw(data, options);
            },1000);
        }
    },"JSON");
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried your code and I am having the same problem. Sometimes in mozilla I am getting the spinning icon at the top and transferring from www.gstatic.com at the bottom, but nothing loads. However again after waiting and refreshing the page the charts will load. I do like your re-arranged code better, but unfortunately I am still having the problem. However again once the charts load they load everytime, until I close my browser

Comment: Stupid thing is that I just tried it in internet explorer and it works fine. It seems the problem is in mozilla firefox. Can't comment on any other browsers at the moment. I tried downloading loader.js at work earlier and I had the same problem, plus I don't think they like us doing that.

Comment: i've had similar problems using mozilla in the past, thought it was resolved and seemed to work fine for me today. last i recall, there was some sort of certificate problem with _www.google.com_, which `loader.js` makes calls back to...

Comment: I have been at this for hours. I used your code, then I tried different variations, and the same thing happens everytime. What I can't understand is why nobody else is complaining of the same problem. I have looked at the google forum and there is nothing.

Comment: could it be only a problem on your end, current internet / network connection...? -- just thinking out loud here, have a way to test from another network / location / computer? -- i know my issue dealt with internal network security restrictions, etc -- which didn't help matters since internal app anyway...

Comment: Well I had the problem at work, then when I went home I had the same problem. Once it loads the first time everything is fine,but try telling that to a client. Or I could just cross my fingers and hope they are all using internet explorer heh heh

Comment: so frustrating, probably won't help but you could try loading previous versions, instead of `'current'`, try `'45'` back to `'41'`  --> `google.charts.load('current', ...` -- `google.charts.load('45', ...`

Comment: Will try that later. Stuck on a different problem non chart related, but I will look into this later.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Whitehat, but the problem was that Mozilla Firefox had a built in popup blocker which was blocking google charts. I know I know, schoolboy error. I am however using your re-configured code